# Using ISOdatetime when only have date and hour in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have date time data in 4 columns of my dataframe. I am wanting to create a single column with the date time.

A small example (apologies for poor formatting I'm working off a phone)

```
2014 3 1 23 2.1
2014 3 2 0 4.7
2014 3 2 1 2.4
```

So the above gives the data (final column) for three time steps an hour apart, 2300 (11pm) on 1st March 2014, midnight that night and 0100 (1am) on the 2nd March 2014.

I want to create an extra column that would have "2009-03-01 23:00:00 GMT".

I tried using

```
Mytimes <-with(my data,ISOdatetime(year,month,day,time,0,0)
```

Where my columns are year, month, day, time, datavalue, but get as output "2009-03-01 EST" with no hour data. I can then add this column to my dataframe

I'm not particularly worried about the time zone, that's just what the examples looked like.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. This works fine for me: `mydata<-data.frame(year=2014, month=3, day=1, time=23,val=2.3);with(mydata, ISOdatetime(year,month,day,time,0,0))`

Comment: Yes it looks to work for hour!=0 or 24, so looks like just midnight that's the problem, so maybe it is working and just truncates there. Thanks, been playing with a large dataset and the first few dozen times are all midnight

Comment: The time simply isn't printed at midnight. Not printed != not there.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, since I couldn't see it I was assuming I'd made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

See comments from MrFlick and Joshua, midnight time is not shown, but is there.

Comment: Just to put your mind at ease, make a sequence  `as.POSIXct("2014-01-31 23:59:57") + (1:5)` then you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
> require(lubridate)
> input <- read.table(text = "2014 3 1 23 2.1
+ 2014 3 2 0 4.7
+ 2014 3 2 1 2.4")
> # create date column
> input$date <- ymd_h(paste(input$V1, input$V2, input$V3, input$V4))
> 
> input
    V1 V2 V3 V4  V5                date
1 2014  3  1 23 2.1 2014-03-01 23:00:00
2 2014  3  2  0 4.7 2014-03-02 00:00:00
3 2014  3  2  1 2.4 2014-03-02 01:00:00
```